# How would I compare a single RGB value with a collection to find the closest match using the CIE94 formula - in Ruby,

Tags: ruby, math, rgb

I have an RGB value, and I would like to find the closest match to that RGB value from a collection of 120 colours.

From what I gather, one of the most accurate ways of implementing such a check is to use the [CIE94 formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94).
However, I am having trouble implementing this using Ruby.

How would you suggest I do this?

```
          R1, G1, B1 = pixel.red, pixel.green, pixel.blue
          c = Colour.first
              R2, G2, B2 = (c.red * 256), (c.green * 256), (c.blue * 256)

              C1 = Math.sqrt((G1**)+(G2**))
              C2 = Math.sqrt((B1**)+(B2**))
              CAB = C1 - C2

              DA = G1 - G2
              DB = B1 - B2

              DH = Math.sqrt((DA** + DB** - CAB**))

              divergence = Math.sqrt( ((R1-R2)/2)** + (CAB/ (1+(0.048*C1)))** + ( DH / ( 1 + ( 0.014 * C1))** )
```

Following one of the answers suggestion to use LCMS, I just realized that RMagick (Imagemagick) the ruby library I am using, actually pulls in LCMS.  This implies that I may have access to some of this functionality - 'pre-baked'.  Is anyone aware of a way to achieve the above using RMagick?

Comment: As a first step you need to show the code you've written. It's easier for us to correct your code than to write it from scratch.

Comment: No prob, ive updated by post to show my code.

Comment: Have you finished this snipped because I could use it if you have!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a *lot* more tricky than you might expect. For many reasons.

The primary issue is that RGB space is a device dependent space - RGB values that look similar on one device need not look similar on another. (If you think this sounds unlikely - there is a huge history of issues between getting good color correspondence between mac / win / SGI due to the different assumptions made by the OS about monitor gamma.)

The second issue is that the perception of difference between two colors depends heavily on the surrounding colors / viewing environment. I.e. two colors may look different when viewed in a dark surround in a dark environment, but similar in a white surround in a light environment.

With these provisos in mind Delta CIE 94 is a decent measure of color similarity.

You'll calculate it by converting each color from RGB to XYZ and then to Lab.
The RGB to XYZ transformation is device dependent - there are some simple standard transformations floating about for it, such as [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB), but their applicability to real devices is questionable. The transformation from XYZ to Lab is complicated and can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB) - for your reference whitepoint you'd use the white point of your device (or sRGB if you're using the standard).

Finally you can use the formulae you have listed above to do the final transformations.

Since this is all relatively painful, you may have better luck calling out to a proper color management tool like [LCMS](http://www.littlecms.com/)

Comment: that is a superb answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for taking the time to put it together.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. I've yelled about some of your points for years, because amateur photographers don't understand the issues of color-spaces, their environments, and reference points.

Comment: Just as a quick followup - i've got the conversions ticking over nicely and it seems to be matching quite nicely. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more tricky than you might expect. You need to convert to convert from RGB → XYZ → LAB → LCH and *only* then you can apply the CIE94 formula. Take a look at the implementation in Chroma.js and port the parts you need to Ruby:

https://github.com/gka/chroma.js